# How to create a macro that creates other macros (that takes arguments)?

Tags: macros

I want to create a macro, namely `\newpoint{<point name>}{<point style>}`, that creates macros like `\Point<point name>{<x coord>}{<y coord>}{<label>}`.

I've seen [How to define a macro to create a new macro with a name passed as its argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25452/how-to-define-a-macro-to-create-a-new-macro-with-a-name-passed-as-its-Argument) which is half way through as it does not show how to make the created macro receive arguments.

I tried:

```
\newcommand*{\newpoint}[2]{%
   \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \newcounter{point#1}\setcounter{point#1}{0}%
   \def\csname Point#1\endcsname (##1,##2)|##3;{%
        \stepcounter{point#1}\fill[#1] (##1,##2) circle (2pt) node[above](#1-\thepoint#1){##3};}%
}
```

But it didn't work, appearently `Use of \csname doesn't match it's definition` and honestly... I don't know what I'm doing anymore.

Here is my M(**N**)WE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\newcommand*{\newpoint}[2]{%
   \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \newcounter{point#1}\setcounter{point#1}{0}%
   \def\csname Point#1\endcsname (##1,##2)|##3;{%
        \stepcounter{point#1}\fill[#1] (##1,##2) circle (2pt) node[above](#1-\thepoint#1){##3};}%
}
\newpoint{A}{red}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \PointA(1,2)|A;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\def\csname ...`, the counter stuff seems very bad. What exactly are you trying there?

Comment: This is actually a simplified version of what I'm doing, the macro `\PointA` does way more than just the circle. But essencially, that's it, it does some drawing and uses automatic naming, therefore the counter is absolutely mantadory here. Using `\expandafter` gives a new error `Undefined \thepoint` , which means `\thepoint#1` is not working, I may have to change the question...

Comment: really are you sure you want to allocate a new counter for every point (in classic tex for example that would limit you to 100 or so points) or a lot less if you have loaded many packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I had no idea about that, but I think my drawing won't have as much as 100 Points. After done with one drawing I reset the counter. Are there better ways to Keep track of the Point numbers?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aren't all current LaTeX distributions etex-based, so that you can easily create thousands of counters?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum yes sure but still it's almost always the wrong thing to do including here where it appears to be re-allocated each time it is used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, for each new point a counter is allocated. Then for each use of the point that particular counter is incremented so that the node names will be different, like `A-1`, `A-2`, etc. for point `A`, `B-1`, `B-2`, ... for point `B`, etc. Howver, if necessary this can be done also without more than 1 counter.

Comment: I have added that solution (without extra counters) to my first solution.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum yes the question got edited:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess your crystal ball is no longer working :)

Comment: @PietvanOostrum at least you got the tick, not egreg, so all is not lost!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @daleif remarked, put`\expandafter` before `\def`. And to get `\thepointA` you have to use `\csname ... \endcsname` there. I guess this is what you want:

```
\newcommand*{\newpoint}[2]{%
   \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \newcounter{point#1}\setcounter{point#1}{0}%
   \expandafter\def\csname Point#1\endcsname (##1,##2)|##3;{%
        \stepcounter{point#1}\fill[#1] (##1,##2) circle (2pt) node[above](#1-\csname thepoint#1\endcsname){##3};}%
}
```

And here is a solution without a real counter for each call of `\newpoint`, based on the solution with a pseudo-counter by @egreg, but with an increment of the pseudo-counter, each time the `\point<name>` macro is called.

```
\newcounter{pointnumber}
\newcommand\StepPointNumber[1]{%
    \setcounter{pointnumber}{\csname number@point#1\endcsname}%
    \stepcounter{pointnumber}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname number@point#1\endcsname{\thepointnumber}%
              \expandafter\show\csname number@point#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\newpoint}[2]{%
   \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \expandafter\def\csname number@point#1\endcsname{0}%
   \expandafter\def\csname Point#1\endcsname (##1,##2)|##3;{%
        \StepPointNumber{#1}%
        \fill[#1] (##1,##2) circle (2pt) node[above](#1-\csname number@point#1\endcsname){##3-\csname number@point#1\endcsname};}%
}
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why using the pseudo counter would be an improvement as to having each `\Point` having its own counter? To me it seems unlogical.

Comment: As David Carlisle said in the comments, counters are a scarce resource, although in modern LaTeX systems there are 32768 available (of which some 100+ are already in use). So it was mainly an intellectual exercise. But in a very complicated and/or large document with many points (more than 30000) it could be helpful.

Comment: Interesting... Although this was more an approach to reduce the preamble size and easily create (if needed be) other `\Point` like macros, I've been meaning to do something like it for a while, but now I've used to improve my answer in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339172/114143). Thank's for the insights! `;D`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the need to allocate a new counter, unless you want to do arithmetic with it.

The main point, though, is that you need to use `\csname` in the right way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\newcommand*{\newpoint}[2]{%
   \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \expandafter\def\csname number@point#1\endcsname{0}%
   \expandafter\def\csname Point#1\endcsname (##1,##2)|##3;{%
        \fill[#1] (##1,##2) circle (2pt) node[above](#1-\csname number@point#1\endcsname){##3};}%
}

\newpoint{A}{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \PointA(1,2)|A;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, the counter made no sense. I had forgot the `\stepcounter` inside the definition of `\Point#1`. I've edited the question...